# How to provide expression as value inside an ssm document?

Tags: aws-ssm

I would like to add a server to an ausostaling-group using SSM document, if the group has n instances running - i want to have (n+1).

Since this stack is managed by cloudformation, i just need to increase the 'DesiredCapacity' variable and update the stack. so i created a document with 2 steps:

1. get the current value of 'DesiredCapacity'
2. update stack with value of 'DesiredCapacity' + 1

I didnt find a way to express this simple operation, i guess im doing something wrong ...

SSM Document:

```
schemaVersion: '0.3'
parameters:
  cfnStack:
    description: 'The cloudformation stack to be updated'
    type: String
mainSteps:
  - name: GetDesiredCount
    action: 'aws:executeAwsApi'
    inputs:
      Service: cloudformation
      Api: DescribeStacks
      StackName: '{{ cfnStack }}'
    outputs:
      - Selector: '$.Stacks[0].Outputs.DesiredCapacity'
        Type: String
        Name: DesiredCapacity
  - name: UpdateCloudFormationStack
    action: 'aws:executeAwsApi'
    inputs:
      Service: cloudformation
      Api: UpdateStack
      StackName: '{{ cfnStack }}'
      UsePreviousTemplate: true
      Parameters:
        - ParameterKey: WebServerCapacity
          ParameterValue: 'GetDesiredCount.DesiredCapacity' + 1 ### ERROR
          # ParameterValue: '{{GetDesiredCount.DesiredCapacity}}' + 1 ### ERROR (trying to concat STR to INT)
          # ParameterValue: '{{ GetDesiredCount.DesiredCapacity + 1}}' ### ERROR
```

Comment: note that even if ParameterValue will get the value of '1 + 1' (without quotes) it will fail because its interpreted as the literal string '1+1' rather than evaluate to 2 and then assign to the ParameterValue I expect it to behave.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do calculation inside an SSM document using python runtime.
The additional python step do the following:

1. Python runtime get variables via the the 'InputPayload' property
2. The 'current' (str) key added to the event object
3. The python function script_handler called
4. The 'current' extracted using event['current']
5. Converting string to int and adding 1
6. return a dictionary with the 'desired_capacity' key and value as string
7. expose the output ($.Payload.desired_capacity referred to the 'desired_capacity' of the returned dictionary)

```
    schemaVersion: '0.3'
    parameters:
      cfnStack:
        description: 'The cloudformation stack to be updated'
        type: String
    mainSteps:
      - name: GetDesiredCount
        action: 'aws:executeAwsApi'
        inputs:
          Service: cloudformation
          Api: DescribeStacks
          StackName: '{{ cfnStack }}'
        outputs:
          - Selector: '$.Stacks[0].Outputs.DesiredCapacity'
            Type: String
            Name: DesiredCapacity
    
      - name: Calculate
        action: 'aws:executeScript'
        inputs:
          Runtime: python3.6
          Handler: script_handler
          Script: |-
            def script_handler(events, context):
              desired_capacity = int(events['current']) + 1
              return {'desired_capacity': str(desired_capacity)}
          InputPayload:
            current: '{{ GetDesiredCount.DesiredCapacity }}'
        outputs:
          - Selector: $.Payload.desired_capacity
            Type: String
            Name: NewDesiredCapacity
    
      - name: UpdateCloudFormationStack
        action: 'aws:executeAwsApi'
        inputs:
          Service: cloudformation
          Api: UpdateStack
          StackName: '{{ cfnStack }}'
          UsePreviousTemplate: true
          Parameters:
            - ParameterKey: WebServerCapacity
              ParameterValue: '{{ Calculate.NewDesiredCapacity}}'
```